# AZURE federated SSO MFA Behavior acceptIfMfaDoneByFederatedIdp not bypassing azure default MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, federated-identity

I am trying to enable SSO from onpremis IDP to AZURE portal. SSO to azure portal is successfull. But i am unable to bypass the MFA option asked by azure.

Steps i performed:

1. Created a domain federation configuration with **federatedIdpMfaBehavior** set to **acceptIfMfaDoneByFederatedIdp**  [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-post-federationconfiguration?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. Added authentication method claims attribute in the saml response.

```
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="IDPEmail">
        <AttributeValue>user_email</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
        <AttributeValue>http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/multipleauthn</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

But still AZURE asks for MFA on successfull authentication of SAML response.

Answer (score -2):

Are you using modern auth into your Microsoft 365/Entra ID?

Also, do you have 2SV implemented into your Google accounts? I found this:

"Microsoft Entra ID accepts MFA that's performed by the federated identity provider. If the federated identity provider didn't perform MFA, Microsoft Entra ID performs the MFA"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/internaldomainfederation-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#federatedidpmfabehavior-values

So it may ask for MFA if you does not have similar auth on the other side (just a guess)

Comment: Please, use comments for questions for details. This isn't an answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35612857)